# Implementation of an interruptable method

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to implement a method that blocks on input, but can be Thread.interrupt()'ed. For example, it blocks on System.in.read(), then another thread can interrupt it so it breaks out of the blocking read, with an InterruptedException.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is `BlockingQueue`. One thread will be hanging trying to fetch smth from that queue, while another will populate that queue with elements, for example that thread that performs reading from `System.in` populates `BlockingQueue` with elements. so another thread can be interupted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider java.nio.InterruptibleChannel

```
If a thread is blocked in an I/O operation on an interruptible channel then another thread may invoke the blocked thread's interrupt method. This will cause the channel to be closed, the blocked thread to receive a ClosedByInterruptException, and the blocked thread's interrupt status to be set.
```

Here is how to "interruptibly" read data from a file

```
    FileChannel ch = new FileInputStream("test.txt").getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    int n = ch.read(buf);
```

when interrupted by another thread "read" will throw ClosedByInterruptException, it is an instance of IOException.

Here is how to "interruptibly" read bytes from a TCP server

```
    SocketChannel ch = SocketChannel.open();
    ch.connect(new InetSocketAddress("host", 80));
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    int n = ch.read(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's already waiting on another blocking method, simply declare your method as throwing InterruptedException and don't catch the original exception. Or are you asking for something else?